# Pandas import error: module 'bottleneck' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, pandas, package

I have been using pandas, tensorflow for a few months, but suddenly today I cannot import them.
When I try to:

```
import pandas as pd
```

It will show:

```
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
  module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  from pandas.core.api import *
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
  module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 9, in <module>
  from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
  module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\categorical.py", line 36, in <module>
  from pandas.core.base import (PandasObject,
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
  module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 20, in <module>
  import pandas.core.nanops as nanops
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
  module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 30, in <module>
  ver = bn.__version__
AttributeError: module 'bottleneck' has no attribute '__version__'
```

May I know what I can do? I have installed Bottleneck, but seems error still appears.

Comment: Install anaconda. create conda env and then install

Comment: I don't know about this error. But, I usually create a conda environment (for  error free installation) instead of installing libraries in my local machine. May be, you can try that.

Comment: What actions did you take on the machine between the time when it worked and the time when it failed?  For example did you install or remove any packages?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem.
I don't really know what it means, but it seems that something must be wrong in the module 'bottleneck'.
Then I solved it by :

> conda remove bottleneck
>
> conda install bottleneck

Yes, simply reinstall bottleneck, my problem has been solved.
Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, resolved it by upgrading bottleneck then pandas:

```
pip install --upgrade bottleneck
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by (re)installing it `[conda|pip] install Bottleneck`

Answer (score -1):

To solve this I performed the following actions:

- Uninstalled Pandas
- Uninstalled Bottleneck
- Executed `conda install bottleneck`